# Facebook Graph API: Share to user's timeline without leaving your app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

Sharing to a user's Facebook timeline without the user leaving your app used to be simple through a server-to-server API request. This is all it took before:

Permission: `publish_actions`

Request:

```
POST /me/feed?access_token={access_token}

message={message}&link={link}
```

This all changed on August 1, 2018 when Facebook removed the `publish_actions` permission. Their `breaking changes` page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes mentions this a couple of times:

> The publish_actions permission has been removed. Apps that have
>   already been approved for publish_actions can continue using the
>   permission until August 1st, 2018. If you want to provide a way for
>   your app users to share content to Facebook and Instagram beyond this
>   date, we encourage you to use our Sharing products instead.
>
> 90-Day Breaking Change — On August 1st, 2018, the Live API
>   publish_actions permission, which allows an app to publish on behalf
>   of its Users, will be reserved for approved partners. In the coming
>   weeks, a new permission model that allows apps to publish Videos to
>   their User's Groups and Timelines will be announced.

So they clearly want us to use the share dialog, but that doesn't work in my scenario. I'd love to have the old server-to-server share capability back. Is there any way around this? They mention that the old feature is still available for **approved partners**. How do you become an approved partner? There's also mention of a new permission model that's coming. I can't find any reference to that. Has that been published?

**Update**
Interestingly, if you use a Facebook test user, the `publish_actions` permission is still allowed and posting to `/me/feed` still works. Strange.

Comment: No you have to use the share dialog.

Comment: @WizKid Any idea how to become an approved partner?

Comment: I have no idea.